# Is it good practice to define constants of type Scanner outside of main with capital letters in Java

Tags: java

I've just begund learning Java.
My textbooks says it is good practice to define constants outside of main, so I don't change them unintentionally, and with capital letters.
A typical way to define a scanner (java.util.Scanner) to take input from the keyboard is:

```
public static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
```

inside main.

I imagine that Scanners typically aren't changed while the program runs, so it typically is a constant.
Is it considered good practice to define constant Scanners outside of main with capital letters, so the first few lines would be something like this?:

```
package test;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test_class_2{
    public static Scanner KEYBOARD = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
```

Comment: Ever heard of `final`? Also, mutable objects aren't generally considered constants.

Comment: @bcsb1001 to be precise, mutable Objects are not generally considered constants.  a `String` for example could be a constant.

Comment: No, this is not a good idea.  `Scanner`s should be local variables in `main`.

Comment: From [the style guide](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~alundblad/styleguide/index-v6.html#toc-variables): "Constants (static final fields whose content is immutable, by language rules or by convention) should be named with all capital letters and underscore (_) to separate words." In this case the Scanner is not considered immutable, so no, naming it as a constant is not appropriate.

Comment: Kilometers of Mercury

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a good practice, as it is mutable.

Only immutable constants should be declared in CAPS on top, and you should also add `final` keyword which means that the value cannot change. Something like:

```
static final String CONSTANT_NAME = "CONSTANT_VALUE" ;
```

This is a good explanation for mutable and immutable values in java.

> Mutable objects can have their fields changed after construction.
>   Immutable objects cannot. Immutable objects are simply objects whose
>   state (the object's data) cannot change after construction

Answer (score 0):

Java uses the final keyword to define constant.

```
final int PI = 3.14;//ths is a constant and you can't change its value
```

On the other hand keyboard(which you defined as Scanner) is reference to a location at the memory that stores the information of a specific object.Now in the process you can change the location that keybord points, for example:

```
keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);//now keyboard points to a different location at the memory
```

So typically keyboard is not a constant as it is possible to take different values(it is possible to point to different objects) during the execusion of the program.

Comment: `final` only means that the value (primitive value or reference) cannot be changed once assigned. It says nothing about the mutability of a referenced object. If the referenced object is immutable (something that Java doesn't know), it is still valid to call that a "constant", e.g. constant `Strings` are common. Anyway, `final` does not mean "constant", in the naming-scheme context.